# How to use Kohana auto_login()?

Tags: php, kohana

Fairly a basic question but I am not able to find any resource on this. How can I use auto_ login().

It is suggestive that if methods are like,

```
Auth::instance()->logged_in()
Auth::instance()->login()
```

it should be:

```
Auth::instance()->auto_login()
```

but this method is not found. How can I use it? or is it removed in the new version?

Comment: "not found" means your IDE doesnt suggest `auto_login`, am I right? There is no such method in basic `Auth` class (https://github.com/kohana/auth/blob/3.2/master/classes/kohana/auth.php), its an ORM only feature.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have to use it directly like that. You can use it in the get_user method, which can be used by the logged_in method.

An example of this usage in the ORM Auth Driver:
https://github.com/kohana/orm/blob/3.2/master/classes/kohana/auth/orm.php

This is a good starting point for learning how to create your own driver for Auth.